# Bugzilla rest api activation

Tags: rest, fedora, bugzilla

I install Bugzilla on my fedora server. I want to use Rest Api, but can't find how to activate it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be fixed by installing some Perl modules that were listed as optional. What worked for me was enabling mod_rewrite and also installing optional modules pertaining to the Bugzilla API. Make sure that all of the modules you have installed are up to date. You will also want to make sure you enable mod_rewrite so that you can contact /rest/ in your URL instead of /rest.cgi/

Example of enabling mod_rewrite for Windows:
https://tomelliott.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting

List of modules (required and optional):
https://www.bugzilla.org/releases/5.0/release-notes.html

Take a close look at the table for optional modules. Under the "Enables Feature" function, you will see these two perl modules are required for the API to function.

```
JSON::RPC   (Any)   JSON-RPC Interface, REST Interface

Test::Taint 1.06    JSON-RPC Interface, XML-RPC Interface, REST Interface
```

Note that you may need to look at different pages if you're on a different OS, or want to upgrade a different version.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API is not bundled with the official Bugzilla release. You can get installation instructions [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla%3aREST_API#Your_Own_Installation).

Comment: There are no "Installation" instructions in that link. Can u be a little more specific?