# Bugzilla REST API produces only a 404 error

Tags: rest, bugzilla

I have Bugzilla installed on Windows 7, Apache 2.4. It is accessible at: http://localhost:80/bugzilla/ which means when I type that address in my browser, I see the bugzilla homepage, I can login as admin and everything is fine.

I read in Bugzilla's documentation that Bugzilla has a "native REST API" that can be used to interact with it. For example it is alleged that sending a GET to the address: `/rest/version` will return the version of the installed bugzilla; The problem is, it doesn't!

I construct a request like: `http://localhost:80/bugzilla/rest/version` and I get a `404 not found` error. I get this exact result for "any" request out of the rest [documentation examples](https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html).

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

---

Incidentally, checksetup.pl shows that my installation is missing these 3 packages:

`perl-ldap
 mod_perl
 Apache-SizeLimit`

Could this be the cause?

---

Update 1: perl-ldap (Net::LDAP) installed. But cheksetup.pl still shows it as not installed and the problem still exists.

---

Update 2: LDAP installed but the problem still exists :(

Comment: Related but not the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10357621/3195477

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bugzilla installation also retuns "404 not found".
I had to use this URL to work ok: http://localhost:80/bugzilla/rest.cgi/version

Bugzilla installation comes with a default `.htaccess` file that does the rewrite work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteOptions 
inherit RewriteRule ^rest/(.*)$ rest.cgi/$1 [NE] 
</IfModule>
```

All I had to do: "`a2enmod rewrite`" and "`service apache2 restart`" to enable the apache module, then the URL "`website/rest/version`" works ok.

Comment: If /rest/version does not work, but /rest.cgi/version works, this problem may be related to apache modrewrite configuration

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution,
inside the rest API link you have to replace /rest/ to /rest.cgi/

example: The REST API for getting the details of bugs.

==> http:your bugzila ip/rest.cgi/bug (this **rest.cgi** syntax work perfectly)